# Knockout error - Unable to process binding “foreach”

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm having a bit of trouble seeing what's wrong with my code. More likely with the Knockout.js part... It's giving me the following error:

> Message: Unable to process binding "attr: function (){return {href:website()} }"

**HTML**

```
<div class="demo-card-square mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp" data-bind="foreach: favoriteSpot">
  <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
    <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Update</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text" data-bind="text:name"></div>
  <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text" data-bind="text:location"></div>
  <a data-bind="attr: {href: website()}">Website</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var favoriteSpotsList = [{
  venueName: "name",
  venueLocation: "address",
  website: "url",
  image: "<img src='img'",
}];


var favoriteSpot = function(data) {
  this.name = ko.observable(data.venueName);
  this.address = ko.observable(data.venueLocation);
  this.website = ko.observable(data.website);
  this.image = ko.observable(data.img);
};

var AppViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;

  /* Create array of hotspot locations. */
  this.hotSpotList = ko.observableArray([]);

  favoriteSpotsList.forEach(function(spot) {
    self.hotSpotList.push(new favoriteSpot(spot));
  });
};

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Comment: foreach: favoriteSpot ??? u mean hotSpotList , foreach iterates over arrays

Comment: You don't seem to have a `favoriteSpot` property on the view-model. Did you mean `hotSpotList`?

Comment: Thank you gents! Staring at the screen to long.

Answer (score 6):

As `@saj` and `@haim770` mentioned in comment, there is no `favoriteSpot` property on the view-model. So, the data bind should loop the `hotSpotList` to get the website property in it. Like below.,

```
data-bind="foreach: hotSpotList"
```

***There is an easy way to identify these kind of issues, specifically while performing bindings in view***

You just need add a button with click binding, `The Button should be placed before the exception line.`

```
<button data-bind="click: function () { console.log($context); }"> Context Log </button>
```

The above code will log the entire context in the `browser console(F12)`. As usual you will get the exception. And this code will not resolve the issue. But this will be very helpful to identify the issue.

The above code will log the `entire context` of the current operation. Which holds object, property with the value.

Below are common scenarios where as you can exactly find your binding object has exceptions.

*1. Properties are present/missing due to the scope level problems?*

*2. Whether it has case sensitive problem?*

*3. Your object comes under where? Is it a parent, child / Alone?*

*4. Human error which makes exception while binding.*

**There are few other ways to find the object/data in view:**

*1. Logs the root:*

```
<button data-bind="click: function () { console.log($root); }"> Root Log </button>
```

*2. Logs the Current scope data:*

```
<button data-bind="click: function () { console.log($data); }"> Current Data Log </button>
```

*3. Logs the parent data: (specifically helpful when we do looping)*

```
<button data-bind="click: function () { console.log($parent); }"> Parent Log </button>
```

*4. Logs the list of parent data: (specifically helpful when we do looping with different types of parents)*

```
<button data-bind="click: function () { console.log($parents); }"> Parents Log </button>
```

*5. Logs the list of parent data: (specifically helpful when we do looping and access different types of parents)*

```
<button data-bind="click: function () { console.log(objectName.propertyName); }">Property Log </button>
```

**For Example in your case you can do like below:**

```
<!-- Added this button before the exception -->

<button data-bind="click: function () { console.log(favoriteSpot); }">Log </button>

<div class="demo-card-square mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp" data-bind="foreach: favoriteSpot">
        <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
            <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Update</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text" data-bind="text:name">
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text" data-bind="text:location">
        </div>
        <a data-bind="attr: {href: website()}">Website</a>
    </div>
```

When you click the button, obviously the message will be logged as `undefined` in console.

Hope this helps.,